# Wordpress Functions Force Dashboard For All Users

Tags: php, wordpress, dashboard

I have tried to force the wordpress dashboard section as a welcome message for all users and failed. Does anyone have a Function that forces the dashboard for subscribers as they log in?

```
// Redirect admin to the dashboard and other users elsewhere 
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 ); 

function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) { 
    // Is there a user? 
    if ( is_array( $user->roles ) ) { 
        // Is it an administrator? 
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) 
            return home_url( '/wp-admin/' ); 
        else 
            return home_url(); 
            // return get_permalink( 83 ); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have been looking here and tried some functions with no luck. Thank you Brasofilo for your time: http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Advanced%3a_Forcing_your_widget_to_the_top

Comment: // Redirect admin to the dashboard and other users elsewhere
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    // Is there a user?
    if ( is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        // Is it an administrator?
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) )
            return home_url( '/wp-admin/' );
        else
            return home_url();
            // return get_permalink( 83 );
    }
}

Comment: You can [edit] the question whenever needed. Code is unreadable here in comments.

Comment: I have no idea how to make the code readable here

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if `$user` is set and then if it's an array. This prevents PHP notices if WP_DEBUG is enabled.

And then, use the functions [`site_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) and [`admin_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) to set the redirections:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect_so_19305904', 10, 3 ); 

function login_redirect_so_19305904( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) 
{ 
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) 
    { 
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) 
            return admin_url( 'edit.php' ); // Goes to example.com/wp-admin/edit.php
        else 
            return site_url( 'about' ); // Goes to example.com/about/
    } 
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

Comment: John, you don't need to add the solution to the Question. Maybe you should read this: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/185667)

Comment: I can't vote yet since I am new. It seems though as I need 15 points. Thanks for the info again